# Firebase snapshot documentations. I am following a tutorial but i can't figure out how to make this change

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
  appBar: header(context, titleText: "Activity Feed"),
  body: Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
      future: getActivityFeed(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return circularProgress();
        }
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs, // i am getting an error here
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

2nd error case:

```
User user = User.fromDocument(snapshot.data()); // i am getting error here
```

3rd case : `

```
 List<UserResult> userResults = [];
    snapshot.data!.docs.forEach((doc) {
      User user = User.fromDocument(doc);
      final bool isAuthUser = currentUser.id == user.id;
      final bool isFollowingUser = followingList.contains(user.id);
      // remove auth user from recommended list
      if (isAuthUser) {
        return;
      } else if (isFollowingUser) {
        return;
      } else {
        UserResult userResult = UserResult(user);
        userResults.add(userResult);
      }
    });
```

*Here on snapshot i am getting error in every scenario. I don't understand how to change the snapshot formation i should do* [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SamOz.png)

Comment: "i am getting an error here" Please edit the question to show the exact error that you get.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.documents`, try `.doc`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30428458)

Comment: @DaFois this seems like an attempt to answer, not like a comment. If you think it is not a *good* answer, you can ***downvote*** but we don't delete possible solutions

Comment: @DaFois: To expand on Tomerikoo's point, please review this [useful guide on the _LQA_ queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).